# Kafka: How to query a topic's previous state

Tags: apache-kafka

I am pretty new to Kafka and I am wondering what is the best possibility to query a previous/historic state of a topic.

*Example*

- Let's say I have a topic BOOKS which contains the number of books on my bookshelf for each category of books.
- As a key I use the books' category (e.g., "science", "fantasy", "foreign")

Now the following events occur:

At 9 p.m. I have 10 science books and 15 fantasys books on my bookshelf:

```
"science":10, "fantasy":15, "foreign": 2
```

At 10 p.m. I take 3 books:

```
"science":9, "fantasy":13 (unchanged: "foreign": 2)
```

At 11 p.m. I add 5 books:

```
"science":13, "fantasy":14  (unchanged: "foreign": 2)
```

*Problem & Expected output*

What is the best approach in Kafka to query the number of books on my bookshelf at a given time? For example, if I query the number for 10:15 p.m. the expected answer is

```
"science":9, "fantasy":13, "foreign": 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "take" from Kafka.
Kafka is not a queue, it's a log.
Consuming does not take out the record at all, it's just poll based reading.

When you produce a record to a kafka topic, this record will stay in this topic/partition until it expires ( or any delete policy occurs).

So it looks like Kafka might not be the best techno for your need (might use some queue techno like rabbitMQ), but maybe you can develop a bit what you're trying to achieve (working with stateful KStreams could maybe do the job).

Yannick